# T-SQL SUBSTRING with CHARINDEX as Length parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2014

I have the below sql. The AND statement after the where is supposed to ensure that there is indeed second space in the name, for example after a middle name/initial. The name in this column is reverse order, Last, First, Middle. I am trying to grab the First name, which would be the name in the second position, should one exist. I am getting invalid length parameter and not sure why, I thought my AND statement would take care of it.

Sample Data:

```
Consultant_Contacted
Sample Name Test
Sample Name S
Name S Sample2
```

Expected Results:

```
Consultant_Last_Name | Consultant_First_Name
Sample               | Name
Name                 | Sample2
```

I am taking care of names being in the reverse order by looking for the `A.Ordering_pty_name = ''`

```
WHEN A.Ordering_pty_name = ''
AND (CHARINDEX(' ', A.Consultant_Contacted, CHARINDEX(' ', A.Consultant_Contacted) + 1) + 1) > 0
    THEN UPPER(
        RTRIM(
            LTRIM(
                SUBSTRING(
                    A.Consultant_Contacted
                    , CHARINDEX(' ', A.Consultant_Contacted, 1) 
                    --, 100
                    , (
                        CHARINDEX(
                            ' '
                            , A.CONSULTANT_CONTACTED
                            , CHARINDEX(
                                ' '
                                , A.CONSULTANT_CONTACTED
                                ) + 1
                            ) + 1 
                        ) - 
                        (
                        CHARINDEX(
                            ' '
                            , A.CONSULTANT_CONTACTED
                            , 1
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Comment: Some sample data would really be helpful here.

Comment: And expected results too don't forget it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing names can be a slippery slope.

You could use `parsename()`, but the XML approach seems a little more intuitive to me.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Consultant_Contacted varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Sample Name Test'),
('Sample Name S'),
('Name S Sample2')

Select Distinct
       Last_Name  = Pos1
      ,First_Name = case when len(Pos2)=1 then Pos3 else Pos2 end
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                 Select Pos1 = n.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)')
                       ,Pos2 = n.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')
                       ,Pos3 = n.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')
                  From  (Select cast('<x>' + replace(A.Consultant_Contacted,' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as n) X
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Last_Name   First_Name
Name        Sample2
Sample      Name
```

Comment: And this is why I love SO, I learn new stuff all the time. Thanks John, I will give it a try

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator My sentiments exactly!

Comment: I need to explore this `as xml` I've used it like twice, worked like a charm. I'll be accepting, much more elegant solution then my parsing mess.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator I was a slow adopter of XML.  Well worth your time to play with it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the desired results as

```
CREATE TABLE T(Col varchar(100))

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('Sample Name Test'),
('Sample Name S'),
('Name S Sample2');

WITH C AS(
SELECT Col,
       LEFT(Col, CHARINDEX(' ', Col, 1)-1) As Part1,
       RIGHT(Col, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Col), 1)-1 ) As Part3
FROM T
),
CC AS
(
  SELECT C.Part1,
     REPLACE(SUBSTRING(C.Col, LEN(C.Part1)+2,  LEN(C.Col)) , C.Part3, '') As Part2, 
     C.Part3
  FROM C
)

SELECT DISTINCT
       Part1 Consultant_Last_Name,
       CASE WHEN LEN(Part2) < LEN(Part3) THEN Part3
            ELSE Part2
       END Consultant_First_Name
FROM CC;
```